# entitymanager.persist doesn't insert into Database

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactional

I m using  entity manager  to persist into Database . when I call this method : createCraResponse who call entitymanager. persist (). I can not see "insert Sql statement"  in the log  . but after I add a call for a select for example it insert into Database but stop running without exception in log .

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class respDaoImp extends AbstractBaseDao implements resDao {

@Override

    public void createCraResponse(Response Response) {
        entityManager.persist(Response);
    }
```

I extends this class :
AbstractBaseDao:

```
public class AbstractBaseDao {

//  protected Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    private static final  Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AbstractBaseDao.class);


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Name", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: Insert on select is a sign that you either do not have a transaction or the transaction isn't committed. Try annotating @Transactional with MANDATORY - what happens then?

Comment: nothing happened the same result  .